# Problems installing Visual C# 2010 Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-c#-express-2010

I just tried to install Visual C# 2010 Express on my machine (Windows 7) from this website: http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/

I got a file "vm_web.exe" (3.392.840 bytes) and executed it. But then I saw that it was "Microsoft Windows Phone Developer Tools" setup. I'm positive that I did not select the wrong download.

I stopped the setup and tried the same with a different browser (Internet Explorer). Same result. This time I completed the installation. No Visual C# was installed, but lots of tools for phone development.

Then I tried to download the "All - Offline Install ISO image file". But again I got the same "vm_web.exe" file (offering to repair/deinstall Phone Developer tools when started).

Anyone had a similar experience or has an explanation what went wrong?

Comment: I pushed a button within my reach at Microsoft.  Try again in a few days or until you hear back from me, whichever comes first.

Comment: I got feedback from Microsoft, no repro.  Good thing @nithins found you a workaround.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I'm on a different computer now and tried again with IE 8 and it worked correctly. Probably my problems on the other computer had something to do with using Opera and canceling the first installation attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right - the link is pointing to the wrong setup package.  For now, try visiting the main [Visual C# Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-csharp-express) page and install from there.  I confirmed that this is the correct C# Express package.